# How to re render a react server component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Supose I have a React Server Component (RSC) which is fetching data like this

```
const MyComponent = async () => {
  const data = await fetch(.....) 

  return <Child data={data} />
}
```

And in an other side I have a layout using a form which is going to perform an POST action, this action will need to update the data in MyComponent, how could I trigger the fetch action on that component?

(I'm using NextJS)